# How to add padding/margin(?) for website header with CSS

Tags: css, header, margin, padding

Here is a [link to my site](http://timepiecetheatre.com). Still in the process of being built so there's a lot to be done still. That being said:

You can see that the header is stretched to fit the 100% width of the background image behind it. I am looking for something a bit tighter, and set up much more like the footer. Constrained in the center, without loosing the 100% width of the background image.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if I need to provide anymore information.

EDIT:
Sorry, it seems I made a mistake with not posting my code. I'm at a loss using Bigcommerce, because a lot of the code is split between over 50 code files (none of which have the name of "header.html" -of courseeeeee-). So I am sorry for my lack of information with this. This is sort of why I posted. I've searched a lot for information on how to achieve what it is I'm trying to, before I submitted a post, but I wasn't coming up with much that was helping. I'm (clearly) not a coding pro.

If anyone is familiar with Bigcommerce, and knows where I might find the code to post, I have no problem posting it to receive help (and make it easier for my heroes x_X).

Thanks again for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your header an inner wrapper.

```
<div id="Header">
    <div class="container">
       Header Stuff
    </div>
</div>


.header {
   background: url(img);
   width: 100%;
}

.container {
   width: 940px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In future please come prepared with a descriptive question, JSFiddle code, not directly linking to your website and maybe some pictures of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for my faux-pas. Here's the thing --

I'm using Bigcommerce, and there's roughly 50 pages of code with various file names. I'm not exactly sure where to place html for the header. A lot of the HTML files reference something else. For instance:
"%%Panel.NewsBreadcrumb%%"

Tricky tricky. I'm no coding pro (clearly), and my website had the footer to show kind of what I was going for. Which is why I finished off by saying I could include any requested information to receive help.

Thank you for -your- help. I'll search around for the file to input this into.

Comment: Without having ever used Bigcommerce, I can almost guarantee they'll have a Header file or to an extent, a Navigation file.

If that fails, look for mark up in the header and do a 'Find All' in your text editor for that mark up.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning. Make use of the width:#px and height:#px. Sometimes I can't get the width:100% to work due to other CSS/HTML arguments, I assume. If you would have posted your actual code instead of linking, I probably could have helped you better...